# AngularJS form validation testing

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

Sometimes forms become very complicated and it is impossible to test every case manually after code changes. 
I already have unit testing with karma on the project.

**Is there any tools or best practices how to test AngularJS form validation with jasmine and karma?**

For example how can I test such form with jasmine and karma automatically?

```
<form name="appForm" novalidate>
    <div>
        Username: <input type="text" ng-model="data.username" name="username" ng-maxlength="15" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        Email: <input type="email" ng-model="data.email" name="email" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        Age: <input type="number" ng-model="data.age" name="age" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="appForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you actually want to make sure when testing form validation.

If you want to be sure invalid form will not be submited, then it is one case. And I don't see problems with this case.

If you want to be sure that appropriate messages are displayed for invalid fields, then, for example, you can make a directive, that is aware of all your possible field restrictions (`'required'`, `'ng-maxlength'`, `'url'`, etc.) and is responsible for displaying appropriate error messages. So you will need to create tests only for this directive.

Example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.username" my-directive name="username" ng-maxlength="15" required />
```

`myDirective` is aware of `required` and `ng-maxlength` restrictions, that were put on the field, & it is responsible for displaying appropriate error messages for invalid state of the field.